# Any advantage to using 'static' on private consts?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Just wondering if there is any advantage to using

`private static const`

instead of

`private const`

for private constants?
Does this change if you have only one instance of the class or multiple?
I suspect that there *might* be some small memory/performance advantage in using `static` if you have multiple instances of the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mmsmatt pointed out, they save a some memory. Usually this is not the best place to save memory however. You should rather worry about memory leaks, about efficient file formats and data representation in general.

A downside of static constants is that all global access is slower than local access. `instance.ident` outperforms `Class.ident`. Run this code to test:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.*;
    public class Benchmark extends Sprite {
        private static const delta:int = 0;
        private const delta:int = 0;        
        private var output:TextField;
        public function Benchmark() {
            setTimeout(doBenchmark, 1000);
            this.makeOutput();
        }
        private function doBenchmark():void {
            var i:int, start:int, sum:int, inst:int, cls:int;

            start = getTimer();
            sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) sum += this.delta;
            out("instance:", inst = getTimer() - start);

            start = getTimer();
            sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) sum += Benchmark.delta;
            out("class:", cls = getTimer() - start);

            out("instance is", cls/inst, "times faster");
        }   
        private function out(...args):void {
            this.output.appendText(args.join(" ") + "\n");
        }
        private function makeOutput():void {
            this.addChild(this.output = new TextField());
            this.output.width = stage.stageWidth;
            this.output.height = stage.stageHeight;
            this.output.multiline = this.output.wordWrap = true;
            this.output.background = true;          
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the class does not definitely need to be instantiated?  Maybe using the non-static approach could save memory in that case.

Comment: For the curious and lazy, I ran this code a few times in debug mode in Flash Player Debugger Version 11.7.700.169 (11.6), and I got results averaging about `instance is 1.01 times faster`. But then, when I moved the `getTimer() - start` calls outside of the `out(...)` calls for each test, I was averaging about `instance is 0.84 times faster`. So it would appear that, contrary to what back2dos asserted three years ago, these days global access in this testcase is in fact _faster_ than local access.

Comment: @mziwisky: Firstly, never benchmark in debug player. It completely skews the result. Secondly, [here's a more comprehensive test](http://blog.controul.com/2009/04/how-slow-is-static-access-in-as3avm2-exactly/) to support my original claim.

Answer (score 6):

`private static const` members are stored once per type.

`private const` members are stored once per instance.

So yes, you are saving some memory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the case.

As stated, the static will be once per type and non-static will be once per instance, so it depends on how many instances you are going to have.

I say that because if you have a component that is only instantiated once at a time (like a prompt pop-up) and you fully dispose of it from the memory after, then it means having as static you are using unnecessary memory since it'll never go away that static variable.
If it's something you'll have multiple instances of (like particles or multiple windows) then yes it's better to use static because they'll share the same variable.